Mariadb does not start on 20.04
root@riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520:/home/riccardo# uname -a
Linux riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520 5.15.0-122-generic #132~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 30 15:50:07 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520:/home/riccardo# lsb_release -crid
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
root@riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520:/home/riccardo# dpkg -l | grep maria
ii mariadb-client 1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 all MariaDB database client (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii mariadb-client-10.3 1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 MariaDB database client binaries
ii mariadb-client-core-10.3 1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 MariaDB database core client binaries
ii mariadb-common 1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 all MariaDB common metapackage
ii mariadb-server 1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 all MariaDB database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii mariadb-server-10.3 1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 MariaDB database server binaries
ii mariadb-server-core-10.3 1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64 MariaDB database core server files
root@riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520:/home/riccardo# apt policy mariadb-server
mariadb-server:
  Installato: 1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
  Candidato: 1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
  Tabella versione:
 *** 1:10.3.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:10.3.22-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
root@riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520:/home/riccardo#

I ran the following command and it still doesn't work, can you help me understand why?
root@riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520:/home/riccardo# sudo systemctl start mariadb
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520:/home/riccardo#

root@riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520:/home/riccardo# systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.39 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-10-09 16:05:26 CEST; 9min ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 3046082 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 3046083 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 3046085 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= || VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ] && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSIT>
    Process: 3046093 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 3046093 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

ott 09 16:05:26 riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520 systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.39 database server...
ott 09 16:05:26 riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520 sh[3046090]: [108B blob data]
ott 09 16:05:26 riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520 sh[3046090]: Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
ott 09 16:05:26 riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520 mysqld[3046093]: [98B blob data]
ott 09 16:05:26 riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520 mysqld[3046093]: Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
ott 09 16:05:26 riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
ott 09 16:05:26 riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ott 09 16:05:26 riccardo-Inspiron-15-3520 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.39 database server.
lines 1-19/19 (END)


Welcome to AskUbuntu! The “Fatal error in defaults handling” message points to an issue in the configuration file. Have you recently upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 or switched from MySQL to MariaDB?

I didn't do any of the things you mentioned. I bought a Dell Inspiron 15 notebook with Ubuntu 20.04 pre-installed and this is my first university exam

"Fatal error in defaults handling" relates to an error reading configuration files. There isn't sufficient permissions on the files or some explicit file is missing.
If you strace -fe trace=file my_print_defaults --mysqld and look for the system call opening a file/dir this will give a more concrete answer as to why MariaDB isn't starting.
Aside, while MariaDB 10.3 is the default in Ubuntu 20.04 its out of maintaince in upstream. Newer release series are available from mariadb.org/downloads.
